# Extract XML embedded in another XML using PugiXML

Tags: c++, xml

Is there an easy way in PugiXML to unescape and load an XML embedded in another XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is

```
xml_parse_result pr = doc.load_buffer_inplace( (void * )response.c_str(), response.size() );
if (pr.status!=status_ok) 
    return pr;
xml_node resultXml = doc.child("soap:Envelope");
resultXml = resultXml.child("soap:Body");
resultXml = resultXml.child( (webmethodName + "Response").c_str() );
resultXml = resultXml.child( (webmethodName + "Result").c_str() );
pr = doc.load( resultXml.first_child().value() );
return pr;
```